# How to, select a list of ids from another table and have it as a column in select in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay so I have two tables, with many columns, but for illustration purposes I have `a` and `b`:

```
a:           b:   
+---+-----+  +---+------+-----+
|id |name |  |id | a_id |size |
+---+-----+  +---+------+-----+
```

What I want is to `SELECT * FROM a` and then for each `a'` in `a` I want to `SELECT id FROM b WHERE a_id = a'.id`. But can I create a single curery such that the results becomes:

```
ab:
+---+-----+--------------------------------+ 
|id |name | b_idx_1, b_idx_2, ... b_idx_n  |
+---+-----+--------------------------------+
```

I tried: 
`SELECT id, name, (SELECT id FROM b WHERE b.a_id = a.id) FROM a WHERE a.name LIKE 'Random Name'` But then I get an error, with the sub-query returning more than one row.

Comment: Isnt this where `join`is used instead?

Comment: `hint:join query`

Comment: Use `JOIN` then `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate `b_id` values from multiple rows into one.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) 
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON b.a_id = a.id
WHERE a.name LIKE 'Random Name'
```

Comment: There is missing an `ON` in the query and could you give an explanation of how it works? Then I will accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try this `join query`

```
select a.id,a.name,b.* from a join b on a.id=b.a_id
```